# How can I deserialize an XML, when I only know the type of an ancestor class?

Tags: c#, .net, datacontractserializer, xml-deserialization

Let's assume I want to deserialize this (I've removed the namespaces to make things simpler):

```
<TextField>
  <Caption>Location</Caption>
  <Name>Location</Name>
</TextField>
```

TextField inherits from FormField, so in my class definition of FormField looks something like this:

```
[KnownType(typeof(TextField))]
[DataContract(Name = "FormField"]
public abstract class FormField
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

TextField class looks like this:

```
[DataContract(Name = "TextField")]
public class TextField : FormField
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Caption { get; set; }
}
```

I tried deserializing using this:

```
internal static FormField Deserialize(string xml)
{
    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(FormField)});
    using (var backing = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        using (var reader = new XmlTextReader(backing))
        {
            return serializer.ReadObject(reader) as FormField;
        }
    }
}
```

I get a SerializationException: "Expecting element 'FormField'..."

Comment: Is `TextField` the root of the XML file, or is `FormField` the root?

Comment: TextField is the root.  TextField inherits from FormField, so TextField is a kind of FormField.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my problem I added a container node to the XML, so that it looks like this:

```
<FormFieldContainer>
    <TextField>   
        <Caption>Location</Caption>
        <Name>Location</Name>
    </TextField>
</FormFieldContainer>
```

I created this class:

```
[DataContract(Name = "FormFieldContainer")]
internal class FormFieldContainer
{
    [DataMember]
    internal FormField FormField { get; set; }
}
```

And my deserialize method looks like this:

```
    internal static FormField Deserialize(string xml)
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(FormFieldContainer));
        using (var backing = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            using (var reader = new XmlTextReader(backing))
            {
                return ((FormFieldContainer)serializer.ReadObject(reader)).FormField;
            }
        }
    }
```

If anyone has a better solution, please share it :)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your model look like this then?

```
public abstract class TextField: FormField
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

just a stab, I actually just started diving into the DataContractSerializer stuff list night oddly enough.

Comment: I added my TextField class above, so you can see what it looks like.